# Cauchy integral formula help needed

Tags: complex-analysis

using Cauchy's integral formula I need to evaluate:

> $\int_C \frac{1}{z^2}$, where C is the unit circle |z| = 1:

By parametrisation I got the answer 0.

However whilst trying to show this using the formula I am stuck.
For f(z) would I use $\frac{1}{z^2} $ or just 1 ?

Comment: You would probably want the generalized Cauchy integral formula which involves derivatives with $f(z) = 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cauchy-integral formula: for a holomorphic function $f(z)$, $\oint_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^n} = \frac{2\pi}{(n-1)!} f^{(n-1)}(a)$, if $a$ lies inside the region of closed curve $\gamma$.

Consider the function $f(z) = 1 \ \forall \ z \in \  \mathcal{\mathbf{C}}$. Now apply the Cauchy integral formula with $n=2$ and $a = 0$.

In short: take $f(z) = 1$